# Not able to get both Icon and Image in Android Actionbar button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

***`I am using a Split ActionBar & I have successfully inflated the menu for my fragment`***

---

**When i used below code** ::

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/java"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/android"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Account"/>

</menu>
```

**I get the output as**::

[image]

---

**When i use second code in an another usecase**::

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/java"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/android"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Account"/>

</menu>
```

**I get the output as below**::

[image]

---

***Problem I am facing***::

- I am not able to get both Icon and button text ?
- Is it not possible to obtain both ? if so how ?
- Or is it we have to use only either one of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **'withText'** value as well in the showAsAction attribute.

So the menu item will now look like,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Account"/>
```

Also, note it will ultimately depend upon the space available in the ActionBar. One cannot force it and in case if space is not enough it will end up as an overflow for the overflowing content.

Comment: I tried with this .... I still get to see only icon ... is there any other setting to be made ?

Comment: Did you try android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:showAsAction="always|withText"`